# Change the value of custom layout's properties

Tags: android

I have a drawable named layout_bg_exp.xml with the codes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/ColorNecessities" android:id="@+id/listExpensesBgColor"  />
    <corners android:radius="5dip"/>
</shape>
```

and color.xml (under values folder) with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="ColorNecessities">#eac49a</color>
    <color name="ColorSavings">#a5e1f7</color>
    <color name="ColorEntertainment">#f1f277</color>
    <color name="ColorInvestment">#a6e9a3</color>
    <color name="ColorEducation">#c2f7ee</color>
    <color name="ColorCharity">#f7c2f7</color>
</resources>
```

layout_bg_exp is referenced in my layout file list_expenses.xml, as described below (Truncated just to show the part that refers the layout_bg_exp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/llBoxDescription"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg_exp">
</LinearLayout>
```

Now my list_expenses.xml is inflated by my RecyclerView adapter,as shown below:

```
@Override
    public AdapterExpensesList.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_expenses, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
```

So my question is, is there anyway I can change the value for listExpensesBgColor, from ColorNecessities to others (maybe ColorCharity or ColorSavings etc), programatically? Actually what I'm trying to achieve is, I want to change the color based on the items in the RecyclerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that something like that should work:

```
GradientDrawable GradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable)v.getBackground();
GradientDrawable .setColor(YOR_DESIRE_COLOR);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_expenses, parent, false);

if(item==<your desired item>)
   {
      v.setBackgroundColor(<YourDesiredColor>);
   }
else if(condition
   {
     .
     .
     .
       so on
```